# keyframe object in and then out of scene

Tags: animation, objects, keyframes, scene

Imagine I am going to take a gun out my pocket and then fire

I can keep the gun next the side of the pocket. How do I keep this out of the scene but then into the scene as my character picks the weapon?

In any other instance where one would like an object to not appear in the scene but then appear. How does one do this?

Comment: You can keyframe visibily properties (object props>visibility)

Comment: How do I do this?

Comment: Know how to use the timeline? If yes, select the frame, then place the mouse upper the visibility prop check box (either render or viewport) and use 'i' key to insert keyframe (or use rmb on it).

Comment: so when he keyframes have been insertng, go to the top right, click the eye icon next to the object. continue keyframing, then click eye icon and continue keyframing?

Comment: Not this one... will explain in a minute

Comment: @Kamran Ali, under the object panel, under visibility, animate the checkbox for **show in renders.**

Answer (score 1):

Object visibility can be animated (keyframes):

[image]

Two visibilities: one for viewport and one for rendering. You may need to keyframe twice.

To add a keyframe, place the timeline where you want then change the visibility checking or unchecking the visibility, then:

- Either place the mouse cursor on the check box and use <kbd>I</kbd>
- Or use <kbd>RMB</kbd> on the check box and choose 'insert keyframe'

[image]

So you can blink an object:

[image]

Comment: What version of Blender is this? In 2.92, when I look under the Visibility section from the Object Tab, I get the checkboxes you show, but not the sliders.

Comment: Sliders? You mean the green lines? I've added them to point out the checkboxes in the screenshot.

Comment: OH! I thought those were variable controls! Okay. Well, that still leaves the question I would have had, then, which is how to keyframe the gradual loss of visibiltiy over time, in sort of a fade effect.

Comment: @R-800, for fading in or out, that should be done with the shaders. No other way, I think.