# Animating an Object to Appear / Disappear

Tags: animation, materials, transparency

I need to animate an object's visibility from opaque to fully transparent in a scene, and this object has many materials that are shared by other objects in the scene.  As I understand it, my only option is to create a single user copy of each of the materials for the object I need to 'disappear', then add a transparency shader to each of these materials and then keyframe that shader's strength (for each material) in order to achieve this.  This seems very complex for such a simple objective.  Anyone know of a better way?

Comment: I personally think the best way is doing that in comp...

Comment: Thank you - I should have mentioned, I am using Cycles to render.

Comment: If you don't want to fade in/out, but simply make objects appaear/disappear you can keyframe object visibility ('visibility' section in 'object properties' tab).

Comment: related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/150660/keyframe-object-in-and-then-out-of-scene/150668#150668