# Keyframe an Object's visibility

Tags: animation, keyframes, visibility

I have an object that is visible, and on frame 30 I'd like that object to be invisible, the same way you would hide an object with 'h' and un-hide it with 'alt+h'. Is there a way to achieve this without an material alpha?

Comment: For 2.8: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/150668/30849

Comment: Or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16009/animate-the-viewport-visibility-of-an-object-within-the-timeline/16010#16010

Comment: Thank you! I have found the answer to my question :)